# Scale Bar is Invisible on Map Area

Tags: qgis, layouts, scale-bar

In QGIS layout, I have two maps. Both showing the same region. The upper Map (Map 2) creates a whitish background (using difference tool) on Map 1. Now I want to put a scale bar. But it is shown only over Map 1. After adding Map 2, it becomes invisible. How to put it on top of Map 2 so that it can be visible?

Comment: Did you try moving it to the top in the items list?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the `items` list, you can see the order that objects will be drawn in. You need to move your scalebar to the top of that list.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Turton. It solved my problem.

Comment: Then please accept the answer